# Transmission 2.52 - 409: Conflict

Tags: web, transmission

I'm using Transmission 2.52 on a Debian server. The only thing I changed in settings.json is username and password. When I try to connect, it ask me my login details but after this, it says:
409: Conflict

Your request had an invalid session-id header.

I looked over the internet but I didn't find anything good. I tried different url like:
host:9091/transmission/
host:9091/transmission/web/
host:9091/transmission/web/#files/

Always the same error.

I am using Debian 4.7.2-5 and transmission 2.52

Any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 16):

I've just experienced this problem myself, and found a solution here: 
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=22013

Basically, remember to add the trailing '/' on the end of your transmission url, for example:

This works:

```
http://10.0.0.4:9091/transmission/web/
```

---

But this gives the **409: Conflict** message:

```
http://10.0.0.4:9091/transmission/web
```